# Fastest way to add a lot of rows in a DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datatable

I have around 200,000 objects that I want to insert in a `DataTable` and show them in a DataGridView as a bound data source. Right now, I'm using this code to insert the rows which takes a long time:

```
public static void InsertAutomaticDataRows<T>(this DataTable dataTable, IEnumerable<T> objects)
{
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

    foreach (var obj in objects)
    {
        var row = dataTable.NewRow();

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            row[dataTable.Columns[property.Name]] = property.GetValue(obj) ?? DBNull.Value;
        }

        dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve the same result sooner? Is there a better way to do this? I just want to show 200,000 items in a GridView. I assume this should be possible.

#### PS:

This is just for a specific case. I know showing 200K records to the user is not a good idea.

Comment: I don't see that this is a bound data source.  You appear to be setting value's to each cell on each row versus setting the `DataGridView.DataSource` property once to a collection, or better yet, to a `BindingSource`.  That way you can keep populating a huge dataset but the DataGridView only displays a couple of pages of data at a time.  It doesn't try to fetch more data unless the user requests it by clicking the scroll bars or pressing Page Up or Page Down.

Comment: Did you try ToDataTable() after GetProperties, and then merge two tables?

Comment: Why not bind the IEnumerable to the DataGridView what is the reaoning to put a Datatable in between?

Comment: @Ralf I use the binding features in a custom control.

Comment: @duerzd696 Could you explain more?

Comment: @RickDavin I set the data later on. I just showed how I fill the DataTable. It takes a really long time to add 200,000 records so I wanted to know if there's a faster way.